# Is possible to install "V8_JS" on SourceForge web hosting?

Tags: javascript, php, webserver, v8, sourceforge

According to the [official guide](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php), I know that I can run a JavaScript code as a server-side language. And, I can install this runtime-engine on my own [XAMPP] server (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/), too.

---

Now, I want to use this runtime as a server-side language, on SourceForge web hosting. So, I have searched on Google, to find the some ways to install [V8_JS](https://pecl.php.net/package/v8js); but, there is no.

Is possible to install [V8_JS](https://pecl.php.net/package/v8js) on SourceForge web hosting? And; if it is possible, please show me the the way to do it.

---

I am using **Windows XP** for my work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about the capabilities of a specific hosting provider's services. Ask their support department for details!